# Looping in clojure and storing to array

Tags: arrays, clojure

I have this piece of code in java

```
public class read{ 
   private ArrayList <String[]> test = new ArrayList<String[]>(); 

    //arr is a valid array 
//br is a buffered reader
while(br.readline())
    test.add(store(arr[]));

public String[] store (String[] str_arr) {
    String a; 
    new_str_arr[] = new String[2];
    new_str_arr[1] = str_arr[0];
    new_str_arr[0] = "Header";
    return new_str_arr;
}
```

How would i be able to convert this into clojure ?

Comment: Storing into an array, I can see, but what does this have to do with looping?

Comment: What is the purpose of class `read`? Could you give an example of usage?

Comment: What i have is actually a reader class reading in data from a file with each line storing each line as an array element into an array. As the number of lines in the file is unknown, i have to use a while loop.

Answer (score 3):

Not clear what you want, however, if want to read text file and store each line to an array of element, and if the file is not huge in size, you can try this:

```
(use '[clojure.string :only (split)])
(split (slurp "file_name.txt") #"\r\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish. You don't store the result of br.readLine() into a String variable, so in your program nothing interesting will happen probably. From the text you provide, maybe this comes close:

```
(use 'clojure.java.io)
(with-open [rdr (reader "/tmp/test.txt")]
  (doall (map vector (line-seq rdr))))

Input file:
123
12
123
12
123
12
123
12
123

Output:
(["123"] ["12"] ["123"] ["12"] ["123"] ["12"] ["123"] ["12"] ["123"])
```

The file is read line by line and is not in memory all at once. The result however is. The `doall` is needed, because `map` returns a lazy seq. When an element of the lazy seq would be realized outside the with-open, the file would already have been closed.